# barbushin / php-imap Как узнать статус полученного письма (новое / прочитано)?

Tags: php

Как узнать статус полученного письма (новое / прочитано)?

Comment: достоверного способа нет

Comment: Может кто-то знает не достоверные?

Comment: недостоверные - это встроить в письмо ссылку на картинку, уговорить получателя разрешить просмотр внешних картинок в почтовом клиенте, и смотреть логи на сервере с картинкой

Comment: Наверное я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Я забираю из своего ящика, свои письма (как объекты PhpImap). Как определить у сообщения статус прочитано или не прочитано.

Comment: а при чем здесь тогда phpmailer?

Comment: Я не только отправляю но и забираю письма с помощью данной библиотеки. Результат меня более чем устраивает. Письма в результате всегда в виде удобного объекта, в нужной кодировке.

Comment: Я не вижу у phpmailer функциональности чтения писем. но в любом случае, с этим вопросом лучше обратиться к документации.

Comment: Не заметил где упамянул phpmailer. Речь о  barbushin/php-imap

Comment: [в своём вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1304571/1)

Comment: в случае использования готовой библиотеки следует обратиться к ее документации или исходному коду

Comment: когда клиент выполняет команду [fetch](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2060#section-6.4.5), флаг seen у сообщения выставляется безусловно («The \Seen flag is implicitly set»). поэтому речь о «непрочитанности» сообщения можно вести лишь **до** получения тела сообщения, то есть пока вы читаете лишь заголовки сообщений, осуществляете поиск и т.д. и т.п. // если используемая вами библиотека позволяет получить лишь заголовки сообщений, то она должна уметь предоставлять вам и полученные от сервера флаги (unseen в частности).